# How to get custom attribute value from adminhtml customer custom field using observer

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, customer-account

How to get custom attribute value from `admin_html` customer field using observer `customer_save_after event`?

Comment: just like you get a custom attribute from any other customer object

Comment: okay, another user object that i get like this .  $request = $observer->getRequest();
        $customer_attr = $observer->getRequest()->getParam('suspend_customer');

Comment: I don't see a customer object there...

Comment: but in event customer_save_after  i get null

Comment: $observer->getCustomer() will return the customer object.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wanted to write in another event.  I can receive a dispatch from the customer in this way another event, but in this event returns an empty,  thank you, you helped me !